# read and write in verilog when having negative numbers and array

Tags: io, verilog, fwrite, fread, negative-number

I am now doing reading input data from txt file and write the results into txt file.

However the results runs in the simulation works well but it fail to link back the the conv module which is o = a+b; the system able to read the values in x.txt and d.txt but cannot link it back to a and b. What is my mistake and how to correct it?

And from the same cases in  i found out that the system cannot write out negative decimal value although it is change to "%d\n" in $fwrite. Any method to solve that? Should i use $dumpfile to get negative number as output??

Here is the content in d.txt

```
56
272
1
-62
75
```

Content in x.txt

```
562
2723
14
-620
751
```

Here is my module code:

```
module conv (input signed[15:0]a,b,
         output signed[15:0] o);

assign o = a + b;
endmodule
```

My testbench code:

```
module conv_tb();

reg clk;
reg signed [15:0]a[4:0];
reg signed [15:0]b[4:0];
wire signed [15:0]o[4:0];

integer ai,bi,oo,i;

conv U1(.a(a),.b(b),.o(o));

initial begin
    clk <= 1'b0;
    forever
    #1 clk = ~clk;
end

initial begin
   ai = $fopen("x.txt","r");
   bi = $fopen("d.txt","r");
   oo = $fopen("o.txt","w");
   #1;
   for (i = 0; i<5; i=i+1)
       a <= $fscanf(ai,"%d\n",x);
       b <= $fscanf(bi,"%d\n",d);
       #4;
       $fwrite(oo,"%d\n",o);
   end
   $fclose(ai);
   $fclose(bi);
   $fclose(oo);
   $finish;
   end
endmodule
```

Comment: adding a begin in the for loop and removing the unpacked array in tb might help

Comment: @Emman after adding begin in for loop and remove the unpacked array in tb there is a problem on tb_conv.v(28): near "$fclose": syntax error, unexpected SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER

Comment: which compiler you are using? here it is working http://www.edaplayground.com/x/3P4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example for writing signed number to a text file using fwrite :

```
module write_signed;
integer out_file;
initial begin
   out_file = $fopen("out_file.txt","w");
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", 3);
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", 2);
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", 1);
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", 0);
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", -1);
   $fwrite(out_file, "%d\n", -2);
   $fclose(out_file);
end

endmodule
```

Which generates :

```
      3
      2
      1
      0
     -1
     -2
```

Comment: If the negative number are generated through the calculation like above, can i replace the 3,2,1,0,-1,-2 to 'o'?

Comment: I would have thought so. If your still having issues with signed number it might be a good idea to try create a minimal example like this check it is working then add in the extra bits as required. NB 16 bit plus 16 bit gives a 17 bit result, you might be seeing underflow/overflow in in some cases.

Comment: i found out that the addition and multiplication of my system works well but when involve in negative numbers the result seem to be differ from the calculation. What is the problem behind it? Is it overflow? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103590/why-the-answer-is-differ-from-the-ideal-calculation

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method to solve your issue is to use a hex value input as shown, convert all negative values to corresponding hex value in the text file explicitly is required

```
module conv ( input signed [15:0] a, b,
              output signed [15:0] o);
  assign o = a + b;
endmodule

module conv_tb(); 
reg signed [15:0] a,b,o;
conv u0(.a(a),.b(b),.o(o));

reg [15:0] Mem [0:4]; 
reg [15:0] Mem1 [0:4]; 
integer j,k,oo; 

initial
begin 
  $readmemh("x.txt",Mem); 
  $readmemh("d.txt",Mem1); 
  oo = $fopen("o.txt","w");
end

initial begin 
  for (k=0; k<5; k=k+1) begin a= Mem[k]; end
  for (j=0; j<5; j=j+1) begin b= Mem1[j]; $fwrite(oo,"%d\n",o); end
end 
endmodule
```